# PHP: Is variable variables syntax an example of reflection?

Tags: php, reflection

I got into a conversation with a coworker and we talked about reflection in PHP language. I insisted that instantiating instances of class using variable variables syntax like following is a reflective technique.

```
<?php

$className = 'Animal';
$animal = new $className;
```

My coworker differed in opinion. I did extensive google search and even read this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#PHP) on reflection. However, to my surprise none of the resources explicitly mentions that this technique is an example of reflection. All I get while doing search is references and examples to Reflection API.

So can someone answer weather this technique is an example of reflection. Also if possible, please point out an authoritative source which explicitly states this.

Comment: This doesn't look like reflection to me.  Reflection is a means to examine a class to observe its metadata (which includes things like member names).  No metadata is being observed here; rather, *a  string substitution is being performed.*  In other words,  whether you type the name of the class out yourself or provide it as the value of a variable makes no difference to the PHP interpreter.   You're looking at a first-class feature of the language itself.

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know for sure that this is how PHP functions.  But since PHP is an interpreter, string substitution is all that is really required to make variable variables work; so it seems unlikely that it could be anything else.

Comment: Python is also interpreted, and so is Javscript. But this construct doesn't work there.

Comment: Because the Python and Javascript "interpreters" do not perform the kind of string substitution I describe.  Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: I can take a class name and method name as input from a web form, and instantiate that class and call the method. Isn't that reflection? How is it different than what this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#PHP) elucidates using Reflection API.

Comment: As I stated before, I don't think simple string substitution counts as reflection.  You can perform that sort of substitution in an interpreted language quite easily, without spinning up any additional machinery like you have to in languages like Java and C#.

Comment: PHP is a string-oriented language. In its original versions, strings were the only data type (although others were added afterwards).  And it doesn't distinguish strongly between language symbols and strings. I believe the feature is now either deprecated or removed, but it used to be that undefined identifiers were transformed directly to string constant values containing the identifier; this suggests that at the parser level, at least in early versions of PHP, there actually was no distinction between a string value and an identifier ... which makes @RobertHarvey's guess correct.

Comment: Out of interest, javascript *does* have a directly equivalent syntax: since all globally defined values are properties of a single "global" object (called `window` in browsers, but other names in other contexts), you can convert any direct identifier reference to a global value into an indexing operation on that object, e.g. `var d = new Date(123456789)` can be rewritten to `var classname = "Date"; var d = new window[classname](123456789)`.  I don't know enough about Python's object model to be sure, but suspect a similar translation can be applied there, too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I *might* agree in that "simple string substitution" doesn't count as reflection. But, this is a hair beyond "simple" string substitution. And, reflection isn't limited to object introspection (or manipulation) as you initially stated. Reflection is broadly a programs ability to manipulate itself (as though the program itself were the programming domain). I'm still on the fence. But, I'd argue that run-time rewrites of variable names is worth a **well-justified** answer either way.

Comment: And, I'll leave this here for anyone who has more time than me to read it in full: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.394.8266&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @svidgen: It doesn't really matter to me if people want to use the word in the more general sense you describe.  However, I believe that the most common use of the word is the one I described.  In C#, reflection has performance and best practice implications, as it does in Java, implications that are commonly recognized and well-understood.  These languages are not fully introspective by design like Lisp is, and these well-understood implications of reflection do not apply to the OP's quandary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think I understand your point. What do C# or Java or Lisp have to do with it at all? Each of these languages approach reflection in their own way, I'm sure. But, reflection (in computer science) is a term that refers to a fairly broad set of things... How *isn't* the broad, comprehensive understanding relevant here? (Especially considering as how the formal concept predates the usage you're referring to ...)

Comment: @svidgen: I'm referring to *common usage.*  Yes, I agree with your academic definition of the word.  I'm saying that, while that academic definition does satisfy the general case, the word itself has a more specific meaning in industry.  I also said that I didn't particularly care how people use the word, but if they're using it in the context of C# or Java (or even PHP), it has a rather *specific* meaning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But, you're then assuming that C# and Java (and other "industry languages") both dominate and dictate terminology in programming. ... That seems utterly wrong to me.

Comment: @svidgen: They certainly dominate over languages like Lisp, by a very wide margin.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But not over python or JavaScript. And PHP *potentially* dominates over C# (depending on the sources you believe). ... But again, how is that *relevant?* ... Individual languages don't have authority over CS concepts. They're more generally "consumers" of CS, not "producers" of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72051/discussion-between-svidgen-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 3):

**No**

Some languages would have to do that via reflection, but in PHP it's a first class feature of the language.  It's also not reflection to use eval to do the same thing.

Reflection takes something, an object, type, the name of a function or variable and returns information about it and let's you use the returned information to do stuff (including possibly calling constructors if the thing is a class).

To give an analogy: multiplication can be done via addition, that doesn't make multiplication addition.

In a comment to the OP @RobertHarvey says that he isn't sure it isn't Relection because he isn't sure how the interpreter is creating the new object, but he is missing the point.  Regardless of how the interpreter is getting the new class it isn't Reflection because it isn't the APPLICATION getting information about itself and then creating a new class with that information.  If the application had gotten a list of class names and picked one at random and created the class that way, that would be Reflection.  For a concrete instance it isn't Exec or sp_execSQL that gives TSQL the ability to do Reflection, it is the sys and information_schema views in combination with them.

I would suggest that you read some of the questions asking how to add reflection to languages that don’t support it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453/how-can-i-add-reflection-to-a-c-application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353022/reflection-support-in-c/1353133#1353133 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118705/call-a-function-named-in-a-string-variable-in-c. In particular note how the fundamental problem is that either the language doesn’t supply access to the required information or that the construct might not exist at runtime.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with a general answer of "no" yet. But, I'm also unconvinced that reflection necessarily deals in objects. Nor am I convinced that reflection must be implemented in such completeness to be considered reflection...

Comment: @svidgen: why call it reflection if doesn't do what reflection does? Would you call a user defined factory class that took either a string or a type and returned a new instance of the class reflection?  I certainly wouldn't, any more than I would call a dictionary of functions that returned a new instance of a type reflection.  The details of how it operates and what needs to be done to get it to do it are important.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't. But, reflection is much simpler than your answer infers. It's nothing more than a program being able to "reflect" upon itself. (The power to examine and manipulate itself). The means by which this occurs do not diminish reflectiveness. And while a more limited reflective ability is *less reflective*, it's not *not reflection.* ... Your answer seems to limit reflection to the manipulation of instantiable objects. And, that would incorrectly imply that non-oo languages (and non-oo areas of on langs)  cannot reflect.

Comment: @svidgen: I certainly didn't limit it to instantiable objects, object types includes interfaces and static classes.  Reflection means that there is a method of getting information about the code at runtime.  Javascripts `for(property in Object)` would qualify.  Vbscripts `GetRef("name")` or Eval wouldn't.  The example given by the OP doesn't allow examining.

Comment: True. Your answer refers to "object types." But, it's a minor difference. Point is, you're defining reflection in OOP terms, and it's not simply an OO ability.

Comment: @svidgen: I certainly didn't mean to limit it to OOP, OOP just has good handles for describing it.  I've tried to make it a bit more vague, and non-oop, hopefully I haven't made it less clear...

Comment: @comments don't work in answers; the original commenter doesn't get notified.  It's not the greatest way to do things; if you wanted to respond to a comment, you should have responded to it in the comments.

Comment: Finally, it might not seem like reflection to you because you can't observe the introspection that might be occurring, but it might be occurring nevertheless, internally to the PHP interpreter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: to your final point, it might indeed, but my point is that is irrelevant.  Just as `v = getValue(o)` might have reflection being used inside the function, but it in itself is not reflection. Reflection in a program is done explicitly by the program, otherwise every line of code is posibly an example of reflection being used

Comment: @RobertHarvey: consider brainfuck.  It is about as far from having reflection as a language can be, but every single command could be implemented using reflection on the part of a [BF interpreter written in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144900/object-oriented-brainfuck-interpreter).  The program has to do the introspection.

Comment: @jmoreno: That's a bit far afield, but I get your point.  Note that I did say in my very first comment at the top of the page that I didn't think this was reflection.

Comment: @jmoreno: I think you are right that it is not reflection. Seriosly. Because: even if the compiler generates code that uses reflection, it is still not reflection. By that logic, every method call in Objective C would be an instance of reflection. Have you read the source of the `objc_msgSend` function? It looks up the method list from the isa-pointer, searches for a method with a given name, and then calls that method - It's not reflection if the reflection has been completely hidden behind an abstraction barrier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is in the `modify its own structure and behavior at runtime` part.

When you write a program in a more "static" style, you know all your instantiated classes in advance. Take any [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). All the created classes are known in advance. Their names already present in code (and I assume that in your example the class name is calculated in runtime). And if there is no such class, any decent language won't compile. And your colleague relies on a string value that is not known in advance and defined at runtime. Here is a tricky part. From one side, any `if` clause can be considered as modification of behavior at runtime. But it's wrong. This behavior is already present in source code. Any condition results in already defined behavior, be it an instantiated class name or called method. But when you define your class name in advance, you never know for 100% sure whether it always results in a valid value suitable for a class name, for example. It's a bit difficult to comprehend and agree with it if your only language is PHP, which is dynamically typed by nature, so probably it doesn't look that weird. But if you'd look at this problem from a statically-typed language perspective, it'd make a perfect sense.

I'm still not absolutely sure about my arguments, but I tried to figure it out, since I agree with you and want to prove it as well.

Comment: So... you're saying this is *not* reflection?

Comment: I'm saying quite the opposite.

Answer (score -4):

The wikipedia article about [Reflection (Computer Programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#PHP) now explicitly states that the usage in question is an example of reflection.

Moreover in the [Implementations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Implementation) the article clearly describes reflective feature as follows:

> Some of these features are the abilities to... Convert a string matching the symbolic name of a class or function into a reference to or invocation of that class or function.

So as far as I can tell at the moment, this is an example of reflection.

Comment: So we'll just take your word for it, I guess?

Comment: Your sarcasm is misguided. I am here to find this out. The Wikipedia article was ambiguous, I made an edit and it was accepted. This made me believe that that was the case. You can contribute an answer if you have one and I'll gladly accept it if it answers my question.

Comment: Making an edit to Wikipedia and waiting a few days to see if it gets reverted is ***not proof.***  Anyone can make an edit to Wikipedia; edits are not "accepted" in that sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I gave this answer as a placeholder until someone with authoritative information can correct it. Unfortunately, that's not gonna happen if question receives downvotes. Please at least upvote the question so that it is seen by more people and better answers can emerge.

Comment: Did anyone *else's* confidence in wikipedia just go down a touch?

Comment: Wikipedia is not a source of authority here. Especially since you are basically citing yourself.

Comment: Furthermore, Wikipedia says here that reflection allows you to "Convert a string matching the symbolic name of a class or function into a reference to or invocation of that class or function." - It doesn't say that the ability to "convert a string..." is an indicator of reflection.

Comment: I don’t want to  get into an edit war on Wikipedia, but 2 of the 3 instances of reflection for PHP are incorrect.  The call_user_func and variable syntax are not examples of reflection.  Both are just variations of eval. Eval is a common feature of interpreted languages, but it doesn’t make them able to perform reflection.